# Parsing help: "身である為"

Tags: parsing

I believe I understand what this piece of description is saying with regards to the subject but I'm confused by the last part and therefore not sure how to correctly parse it:

> 数年前の経歴も局長の立場から調べてあるが、何しろ冤罪によって部局を追放された身である為,

Is "身である為" the same as saying "身のためである" which means "for your own benefit"? In which case the sentence would probably go something like this -  "he was evicted from the department anyway due to false accusations [for his own benefit]".

Comment: なんで文の最後までコピーしてくれないんだろうね。

Comment: The sentence ends like that with a comma, I believe it was giving a reason for something that was mentioned before it.

Answer (score 1):

This is ため meaning "because", giving a reason. It's always a bit hard to translate a sentence with 身 in it. Basically "because/since he is a person evicted from the department~".

You must know about relative clauses in Japanese, 走る男 and such, yes? When you want to use a noun to modify another noun, you cannot use です or だ, you have to use である. So 学生である人 = person who is a student.

Comment: I see, in that case the 為 is in reference to something before it (explaining the reason why character A couldn't do xyz which was mentioned before, and the reason is "because he was a person evicted from the department".) And 何しろ (after all) kind of emphasizes that, so "after all, seeing as this person was evicted[…], character A can't do xyz with regards to this person".

Comment: Hmm, I feel "after all" is not a good translation for なにしろ, it's more like "in any case". Like "we looked into their history from the past couple years (and there were a couple interesting things but most interestingly), he was evicted from the company." Something you say when there are multiple different things you could bring up into the conversation, but you want to emphasize a certain point from among those.

Answer (score 1):

身 here means one's social status or position but not physical body. It is the same with one in 身分.
為 'for' can mean 'on behalf of' and 'because', here it means 'because'.
"In the capacity of a person who purged for a false charge..."

Comment: For a little more referrence, when a ため-clause (in this case, 追放された) is an event happened in the past time, ため only means 'because', as 'for' in English would do so.